# Error website crop?

Tags: html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pEp0.png

I don't know what's the name, but why i always get this style everytime i access http://forumesia.com 
But the style is ok if i access it in desktop. Only in my mobile phone i got crop little part of the website, how to fix this?

I already using bootstrap css but it still croping like that, any suggestion?

Comment: You're probably missing the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the `head`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually because the device doesn't know to scale the website to the device width.

You should make sure that `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` is added in the `head` section of your HTML

Comment: Thanks but it should be initial-scale=0

Comment: I use `initial-scale=1` on all sites for about 4 years so if `0` works for you fair enough, but the answer is still right :)